# Shutdown (embedded) linux from kernel-space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I'm working on a modified version of the 2.6.35 kernel for Olinuxino, an ARM9 based platform. I'm trying to modify the power management driver (the architecture specific part).

The processor is a Freescale i.MX23. This processor has a "special" pin, called PSWITCH, that triggers an interrupt that is handled by the power management driver.
If the switch is pressed,the system goes to standby. This is done in the driver by calling `pm_suspend(PM_SUSPEND_STANDBY)`.

Given my hardware setup, I'd like to, instead, shutdown the system.
So my question is:

**What is the preferred way for a kernel-space process to trigger a clean system halt/poweroff?**

I suppose there's a nice little function call out there, but I couldn't find it so far.

My kernel code (the file I'm working on is arch/arm/mach-mx23/pm.c) can be found here: [github.com/spairal/linux-for-lobster](http://github.com/spairal/linux-for-lobster), though my question calls for a general Linux kernel approach.

Comment: You could do an `strace` on `init 0` and see which syscalls are executed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most *general* way would be for your driver to invoke `shutdown` as a userspace helper:

```
static const char * const shutdown_argv[] = 
    { "/sbin/shutdown", "-h", "-P", "now", NULL };

call_usermodehelper(shutdown_argv[0], shutdown_argv, NULL, UMH_NO_WAIT);
```

(Presuming you have a `/sbin/shutdown` binary installed).  This will shut userspace down cleanly, unmount filesystems and then request the kernel shutdown and power off.

However, you may be able to do better than this - for example if you can guarantee that there's no disk filesystems mounted read/write, you could tell a kernel thread to invoke the `kernel_power_off()` function (it shouldn't be done from interrupt context).

Comment: That works beautifully. I hoped there would be a solution that did't involve calling userspace, but I guess there's a lot of userspace stuff that needs to be done... Just a detail: shutdown_argv should be const char * const * or [].

Comment: I have used kernel_halt() to perform this on my embedded powerpc, and it did seem to go through the init 0 process.  Do you think I missed something?

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber: Maybe you had a reboot notifier registered that told init to shut down? Ordinarily, calling `kernel_halt()` (or `kernel_power_off()`) won't even sync the disks - it's equivalent to using the `reboot(2)` system call from userspace.