# Set linux power state from kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a little driver that is handling a gpio that when enabled should tell the system to sleep/wake when a button is pressed. If its held down it should power off.

On WinCE there is a very easy to use mechanism (SetSystemPowerState) but there doesn't appear to be something similar on linux.

We also don't have dbus...

update:
I may have found the answer

[Shutdown (embedded) linux from kernel-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296686/shutdown-embedded-linux-from-kernel-space)

Though it doesn't really say how to sleep but i think I'll be able to figure the rest out. This doesn't seem like the proper way to handle a linux kernel driver since the module is built into the kernel. It doesn't appear that I have all the power states available to switch to without adding packages outside of the kernel.

Comment: If you find an answer to your own question, it's best if you post it as an answer, rather than an update to your question. That way, the system, search engines and people would know that the question is answered. You can later also accept your own answer.

Comment: I wouldn't really consider it a good or complete answer. Its not really telling me how to change power states, its a generic way to call commands on a user command line. And I have no program in our platform that will set the sleep state. I'm still looking for a more complete answer.

I posted a link to an answer that I feel is more of a dirty work around.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suspend your system entirely, you can use /sys/power/state interface like belows.

```
echo "mem" > /sys/power/state
```

It calls state_store() function in [kernel/power/main.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/power/main.c#L338) to suspend your system into memory. Instead of "mem", you can use "standby" or "disk" only if your system supports them.

Answer (score 0):

The most general way would be to initiate the process from kernelspace as a userspace helper:

```
static const char * const set_power_argv[] = 
      { "/bin/echo", "mem", "/sys/power/state", NULL };

call_usermodehelper(shutdown_argv[0], shutdown_argv, NULL, UMH_NO_WAIT);
```

However, location of echo command and power driver can differ in your system.