# Postpone interrupt action

Tags: linux, interrupt

I'm trying to do something odd to which I've not found reference in the archives. On a Freescale iMX6 processor, there's an input line that generates an interrupt after being pressed (the 500mS delay does not work), the intent of which interrupt is to notify the system of a request for an orderly shutdown. On the system in question, the button attached is also attached to the Enter key GPIO. The generated interrupt appears to be a falling edge/rising edge (or vice versa, it matters not) separated by about 75mS or so. The interrupt does not repeat unless the key is released and pressed again.

The bit to clear the interrupt in the ISR is in a register allocated and held by the Real Time Clock driver (a side effect of the Freescale architecture) so I have to embed my interrupt handler inside the RTC driver, which of course has its own interrupt code.

I thought myself clever when I implemented the suggestion to question [18296686](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296686/shutdown-embedded-linux-from-kernel-space) regarding shutting down (embedded) Linux from kernel-space, but that fails to distinguish between Enter and power-off. I need to detect the power-off interrupt, wait ~750-1000mS, and check whether the button (the <Enter> key is attached to a GPIO) is still depressed, thus signalling a power-off.

I was thinking a poll(2) interface to the driver, but since the driver is really the RTC driver, the interface confuses me, and I'm looking for help in implementing this.

Comment: "but that fails to distinguish between and power-off" - didn't understood this moment. Can you point to exact page of the manual of Freescale iMX6 ? I can't understand how RTC can own the entrire ISR register.

Comment: Confusion understood - I used some angle brackets for emphasis, not knowing that those were metacharacters. Sorry. And I more closely checked my assertion, and the whole premise for my dilemma was invalid. Thank you. Once again, trying to explain to another person deepens ones own understanding of the task.

Comment: You made it even more confusing what means "Enter Key Gpio" you have a matrix keypad attached to gpio? Also if you really want some help point to the technical reference manual of this processor. Cause i need to look at rtc driver code, to see if interrupt can be shared. Or if you can attach button to any other gpio pin that is not shared with rtc, then your task is not a problem at all.

Comment: Yes there is a key matrix, but that's noise, I admit. But I do have a problem. I'm pretty sure (this is 3.10.17 kernel) that rtc_snvs.c reserves from 0x34 for 0x58 bytes, based on the imx6qdl.dtsi file that I have.  0x34 is the SNVS_LPLR register. In IMX7DQRM.pdf Rev.3 from 07/2015, you'll see that the poweroff interrupt can be cleared using SNVS_LPSR.18, at offset 0x4C. The RTC driver reserves from 0x34 to 0x92, so register 0x4C a conflict. I should split RTC IO into high and low regions, leaving a hole at 0x4C? Is that a good way to go?

Comment: Yep - nice i ll have a look.

Comment: rtc_snvs.c reserves from 0x34 TO 0x58. Mea culpa. Still thinking of breaking that up to be 0x34 to 0x48 & 0x50 to 0x58 if that's reasonable. I don't think there's struct resource like object with a hole in it :)

Comment: My solution was to split the one devm_ioremap_resource() call into two, one allocating from 0x34 to 0x48, and the second from 0x50 to 0x58, leaving 0x4C unscathed. All ops are relative to the original base of 0x34, so nobody's the wiser. I'm sure there is a more Linux-ey way to do it, but I'm trying to earn a living here. I won't submit the patch.